# What is the difference between bin/sh, bin/bash, sbin/nologin, bin/tcsh, etc?

Tags: ssh, plesk

I am new to linux so please go easy and talk slow =)

In Plesk I have some options for accessing the server over SSH. I just want to connect, add my public key and run rsync for backup.

1. What is the difference between these options?
2. Which option should I choose?
3. What are these? They look like directories to me.

Access to the server over SSH:

- /bin/sh
- /bin/bash
- /sbin/nologin
- /bin/tcsh
- /bin/csh
- /bin/ksh
- /bin/bash (chrooted)
- /bin/rbash

Here is an image of the Plesk control panel:

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Use /bin/bash**

> What are these? They look like directories to me.

These are different options for default shell given to users who connect via SSH

If you haven't used any of these shells before, I think bash is the best option for you. Most tutorials and articles for linux commands online assume you are using bash.

However, you have two options for bash: `/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash (chrooted)`.

To do backups, you will probably need the bash to have full access to execute all commands.
I'm not sure whether you can get what you want done with a chrooted bash.

Basically, chrooted bash is for avoiding mishaps.

To know more about chrooting, you can read [this article](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/chroot-ssh-env.en.html)

Comment: which one is the best for security if you also have customers on your server.

Comment: If this is a hosting server you have purchased from third party, and your customers also demand SSH access to the server, I think your best bet will be chrooted bash. Please do read about chrooting to understand its pros and cons.

Answer (score 5):

Most of options are various [Unix shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell). A shell is basically what interprets the text that you type in the window.  Some people prefer one shell over others. If you are not familiar with any shell in particular, pick one based on your needs [Comparison Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know, you should use /bin/bash.  It's the most popular, and will be the easiest for you to get help using.  That said, they all do the same thing, just in slightly different ways.

Comment: with the exception that /sbin/nologin will deny shell access completely.

Comment: Then what is `nologin` used for?

Comment: preventing users from logging in.

Comment: Any difference from the Forbidden option here?

Comment: Chances are that forbidden will just close the connection if users try to connect, and /sbin/nologin will display some error message telling them to contact their administrator or some other generic message.  Functionally, they will do the same thing, which is restrict shell access.